# Ubuntu 12.04.5 is installing Apache 2.4 not 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 12.04.5, lsb_release -a output:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

However, running

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Installs apache 2.4, not apache 2.2 as I expected. The output of "apache2 -v" is:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb  4 2015 14:21:10
```

The contents of my /etc/apt/sources.list is:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main restricted universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates main restricted universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
```

As I understand, isn't Ubuntu 12.04 meant to use Apache 2.2? How can I get the server to install the correct version of Apache?

I had to remove http:// from the sources.list quote as I don't have enough reputation to post the links, but the http is there in the actual file.

Comment: For future reference: by formatting sections of configurations files as code rather than blockquote you won't run into the problem of them being considered URL's

Comment: Check for files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to check in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` as suggested by Michael Hampton. I had some extra sources in there.

Answer (score 0):

First check what are the packages available,

```
apt-cache showpkg <pachagename>
```

The above command will display list of available versions for this package. Check if your version is available post that you can specify version for installation.

```
apt-get install <packagename>=<complete version name>
```

Example:

```
apt-cache showpkg apache2
apt-get install apache2=2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7
```